# Google App Engine - Production Only - Module Import Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am getting this error when running the app in production. It works fine in my local environment. But, after I upload to server, it throws this exception.

The test_handler module exists in test package (and it works fine in local). I believe that the entire folder structure will be uploaded to the server, when we upload.

Also, is there a way to see the entire folder structure in the Google Application Account online?

============================================================================

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name test_handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/mad-scribe/1.346944987034829366/url_handler.py", line 15, in <module>
    from test import test_handler
```

Comment: I think what gets uploaded may be determined by what you've put in app.yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the package name. I named the package as 'test', which might have stepped on the shoes of some other package.

`from test import test_handler`

Renaming the package name (test -> test_handlers) fixed the issue.

Thanks to all who responded to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can now download the source if you were the developer who uploaded it.

This should give you a concrete understanding of what was uploaded.

**AppEngine Docs:** [Downloading Source Code](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Source_Code)

Comment: Thanks for the link, which helped to download the source code in Google App Engine.